# Does Data Model always refresh along with the refresh of Power Query and only start after Power Query refresh is complete?

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot, datamodel

I would like to confirm if data model will be refreshed together along with the refresh of query even we never open Power Pivot UI and only start after the query refresh is complete

This my current VBA codes to trigger PQ refresh,

```vb
Sub RefreshAll()

'Disable background refresh

Dim lCnt As Long

With ActiveWorkbook
    For lCnt = 1 To .Connections.Count

        If .Connections(lCnt).Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
            .Connections(lCnt).OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        End If
        
    Next lCnt

End With


'Start refreshing all
Dim i As Integer


'Section for Queries
Dim queryNames(1 To 3) As String
Dim queryName As Variant

queryNames(1) = "Query - Dummy_1"
queryNames(2) = "Query - Dummy_2"
queryNames(3) = "Query - Dummy_3"


For Each queryName In queryNames

ThisWorkbook.Connections(queryName).Refresh
DoEvents

Next queryName
```

I am wondering if I need to add the following codes next to ensure my Data Models will be refreshed accordingly with the latest data after PQ refresh complete, I worry Data Models will not follow along after PQ refresh complete or start the refresh before PQ refresh is complete (this is where I am confused)

```vb
'Section for Data Models (I am not sure if I need to add this section)
Dim datamodelNames(1 To 3) As String
Dim datamodelName As Variant

datamodelNames(1) = "Dummy_1"
datamodelNames(2) = "Dummy_2"
datamodelNames(3) = "Dummy_3"


For Each datamodelName In datamodelNames

ThisWorkbook.Model.ModelTables(datamodelName).Refresh
DoEvents

Next datamodelName
```

Thank you everyone!!
MZ

As provided in the codes above. I am not sure Data Model will refresh after PQ refresh is complete or start together without capture the finished PQ refresh (either scenario will lead to inaccuracy in my Power Pivot data)